# How can I extract data from a list without pulling additional dimensions with it in R?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a list that was created in R by the aggregation of multiple .nc files (cmip6) for temperature.

[image]

I want to pull the 'data' out for a single timestep (month), which would be of size 1 x 256 x 512, as I want to write it out to a new file.

My problem is that when I try to access the data, it has the lat and lon dimensions associated with it.

`data_extract<- test$Data` returns:

[image]

Whereas, I want it to have this structure (this is an example of other data I have used):i.e. Just the data matrix, without the lat lon attributes included.

[image]

Apologies I can't make a reproducible example, as I don't know how to create this scenario (where the additional dimensions are included when you try to access the raw data in a .nc file). This particular list was created by using this code:

```
#-------------------COLLAPSE ALL THE DATASETS------------
  makeAggregatedDataset(source.dir="C:/Users/Documents/Cmip6/mon/",recursive = T, ncml.file = "test.ncml")
#-------------------CREATE THE DIC FILE------------------
  dictionary <- tempfile(pattern = "dicCDX", fileext = ".dic")
test<-loadGridData("test.ncml","tasmax",dictionary = dictionary)
```

The loadGridData function above is found in the LoadeR package in Climate4R (https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/climate4R)

`unname<-unname(test$Data)` doesn't change anything:

[image]

Comment: Does `unname(test$Data)` work?

Comment: @Bas No. Same result (I included it in the main body of the text above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the dimensions attribute you could do:

```
attr(data_extract, "dimensions") <- NULL
```

You can also use `c` to strip attributes

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. As a matter of interest, how would 'c' strip the attributes?

Comment: It's a design decision the creators of R made for `c` to strip attributes. The help for `c` states "`c` is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except names". I personally would recommend the first method since the intent is much more explicit